# Why does some of the home-brew formulas show that they have conflict with another formula?

Tags: homebrew

Some of the home-brew formulas such as this [one](http://brewformulas.org/Hive) show the following conflict:

```
This formula is in conflict with the following:
```

What does this conflict mean and what are its impacts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that some formulas provides common files or common services and cannot be both installed in the same time.

For example the formulas [Sonarqube](http://brewformulas.org/sonarqube)
 and [SonarqubeLts](http://brewformulas.org/SonarqubeLts) conflict because they provide the same application at different version. Another example is the formulas [MySQL](http://brewformulas.org/mysql) and [MariaDB](http://brewformulas.org/Mariadb) that conflict because they provide both a slightly modified version of the same DBMS.

== EDIT

The formulas `hive` and `apache-spark` don't have any conflicts. You can check it with:

```
brew info hive apache-spark
```

It the past there was a conflict because both of these formulas installed the `beeline` binaries but this was solved with this [commit](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/commit/b64c35859510788a31a6ffcbb18b2d10b7946d03#diff-8168d1865e46cd841a8421bac39b4cbd):

```
commit b64c35859510788a31a6ffcbb18b2d10b7946d03
Author: Tim D. Smith <git@tim-smith.us>
Date:   Tue May 5 15:24:12 2015 -0700

    apache-spark: rename beeline to avoid hive conflict

    Reference Homebrew/homebrew#39319.

diff --git a/Formula/apache-spark.rb b/Formula/apache-spark.rb
index 559ea862bb..0bec8aad9f 100644
--- a/Formula/apache-spark.rb
+++ b/Formula/apache-spark.rb
@@ -5,11 +5,13 @@ class ApacheSpark < Formula
   head "https://github.com/apache/spark.git"
   url "https://d3kbcqa49mib13.cloudfront.net/spark-1.3.1-bin-hadoop2.6.tgz"
   version "1.3.1"
+  revision 1
   sha1 "86911b6c8964230a93691bd45589f491c10d36c0"

-  conflicts_with 'hive', :because => 'both install `beeline` binaries'
-
   def install
+    # Rename beeline to distinguish it from hive's beeline
+    mv "bin/beeline", "bin/spark-beeline"
+
     rm_f Dir["bin/*.cmd"]
     libexec.install Dir["*"]
     bin.write_exec_script Dir["#{libexec}/bin/*"]
```

The link you provide in your question is probably not updated with the latest versions of these formulas.

Comment: Thanks @Ortomala. It does make sense for different version of a CI (i.e. Sonarqube) OR slightly modified version of DBMS, However in my case one is framework (i.e Spark) and another is Database (i.e. Hive). - ira wati.

Comment: Thank you @Ortomala.  Clap Clap for your research.